# How to extract a .zip file via bruteforcing using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, zip

I was given a problem to solve using python which stated:

> We've started organising the files to try and make sense of them, but they're all locked with a numerical three-digit passcode.
>
> See if you can write a script to get into this example file `alien-zip-2092.zip` and read the text file inside which we think is named whatever the zip is (so in this case `alien-zip-2092.txt`).
>
> The files should be extracted to the `/tmp/` directory.

I've only gotten so far in my code. It gets the zip file, and to extract it using all the numbers from 0-999 but every time run the code I end up getting just `999` as the result. There is no way to check if the folder has been extracted correctly so I have added `Print (password)` to check.

Here's my code:

```
import zipfile
zf = zipfile.ZipFile("/tmp/alien-zip-2092.zip")
for password in range(0,1000):
    try:
        zf.extract(member="/tmp", pwd = str(i).encode()         
        password = 'Password found: %s' % password
    except:
        pass
print(password)
```

It seems as if my program is overriding the correct file with a blank one with the same name as it is not breaking out the loop after the file has been extracted but I may be wrong.

Printing out the contents of the txt file which is supposedly in the zipped folder would be a great idea but this cannot be done without the rest of the code working.

Why doesn't the correct password print? Anyone have any other ideas to solve the main problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few suggestions:

- don't overwrite the variable `password`, it is your loop variable. Also `i` does not seem to be defined, so you probably want to change that.
- I suggest formatting smalles numbers with leading zeros to comply with the problem statement (maybe use `'{:03d}'.format()`)
- It is not a good idea to use a blank except, as it could hide other errors that could be happening.
- I suggest using [`.extractall()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.extractall) or at least specifying the correct `member` and `path` in `.extract()`.

Here is a modified version fo the code:

```
import zipfile

filename = 'alien-zip-2092'
zf = zipfile.ZipFile('{}.zip'.format(filename))

password = None
for i in range(1000):
    try:
        temp_password = '{:03d}'.format(i)
        zf.extract(
            member='{}.txt'.format(filename),
            path='/tmp/',
            pwd=temp_password.encode())

        # extraction was successful
        password = temp_password
        break          # exit the for loop
    except zipfile.BadZipFile as err:
        # print(err)
        pass

if password is None:
    print('No valid password found.')
else:
    print('Password found: {}'.format(password))
```

Answer (score 1):

You're naming the variable that stores the "Password found" message the same as the iteration variable for your `for` loop, so as soon as the next iteration starts, it overwrites the message that was stored.

You should instead print the correct password and `break` the loop as soon as it is found, and use an `else` block for the `for` loop to handle the case where no correct password is found, which happens if the loop finishes without a `break`:

```
import zipfile
zf = zipfile.ZipFile("/tmp/alien-zip-2092.zip")
for password in range(0,1000):
    try:
        zf.extract(member="/tmp", pwd = str(i).encode())
        print('Password found: %s' % password)
        break
    except:
        pass
else:
    print('No valid password found.')
```